# DirectUpload fails with BadDigest DigitalOcean S3 ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to upload a file but I get an error message like the following:

```
https://sapco.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/b3vcchphzgj5m8p6ld51yk7867uu?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=QTHCA5KKQUHAKMMATAIP%2F20200503%2Fnyc3%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200503T214158Z&X-Amz-Expires=10800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-md5%3Bcontent-type%3Bhost&X-Amz-Signature=7b77a0f1551a262586980b709fdc44a2bc173ab6ae7279385e831493b1d13e53

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
   <Code>BadDigest</Code>
   <BucketName>sapco</BucketName>
   <RequestId>tx000000000000013462bc9-005eaf36fb-3518e03-nyc3a</RequestId>
   <HostId>3518e03-nyc3a-nyc</HostId>
</Error>
```

How can I debug this further?

So far I have tried:

1. Resetting my Access and Secret keys.
2. At first I thought this was related to PWA-related work, but I migrated to an earlier branch and have the same issues.
3. Tried different files: each have the same error.
4. Happens both in prod. and locally.

Update 1: This randomly started working again on production. However it's still broken locally.

With the same file I have the 2 paths for the `PUT` request that leads to the error above.

1. https://sapco.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/11eego5a6r9b4tslx7cex4p9x45u?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=QTHCA5KKQUHAKMMATAIP%2F20200504%2Fnyc3%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200504T005319Z&X-Amz-Expires=10800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-md5%3Bcontent-type%3Bhost&X-Amz-Signature=8d2037f7370eb137facc9d813fe35ed34e055313af06cd66819a72d886dfb018
2. https://sapco.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/z4vc7ujtvid0akqfn4uou46407zl?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=QTHCA5KKQUHAKMMATAIP%2F20200504%2Fnyc3%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200504T005405Z&X-Amz-Expires=10800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-md5%3Bcontent-type%3Bhost&X-Amz-Signature=b4b28cebe56a9b6c12ddfb2cc335b84080a3bfc5e34e2c66e19001230f8b7512

[image]

The issue must be related to the way X-Amz-Signature is computed.

Digging further with `bundle open activestorage` I can see it's roughly here. https://cutt.ly/6yjc7u1

I verified the Content-Length and Content-MD5 are both the same (vs local and prod). (123803 and `ujNHxwCuwZ1mak927GUX3g==` respectively).

Update 2: I tried this in Firefox with the same image and no problem locally. There must be something fishy going on with the cache. I then tried an Incognito window and that also seemed to work. Finally, I did a hard refresh in Chrome and now I've unblocked myself. Didn't quite figure out what was going on but leaving a final piece of information for anyone else:

Chrome Request Headers (Not Working, 400 Error)

```
 PUT /lw5lufemkgb7ww83pdc56qg2gb0j?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=QTHCA5KKQUHAKMMATAIP%2F20200504%2Fnyc3%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200504T013900Z&X-Amz-Expires=10800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-md5%3Bcontent-type%3Bhost&X-Amz-Signature=1ea88bf8550d9bab67b5bca3aa97f7b15f1a44e117dd4f5cea0744c898f70684 HTTP/1.1
 Host: sapco.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com
 Connection: keep-alive
 Content-Length: 0
 Pragma: no-cache
 Cache-Control: no-cache
 Accept: */*
 DNT: 1
 Content-MD5: ujNHxwCuwZ1mak927GUX3g==
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36
 Content-Type: image/jpeg
 Origin: http://localhost:3000
 Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
 Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
 Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
 Referer: http://localhost:3000/
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
 Accept-Language: en
```

Firefox Request Headers (Works)

```
 Host: sapco.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0
 Accept: */*
 Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
 Content-Type: image/png
 Content-Length: 254924
 Referer: http://localhost:3000/
 Content-MD5: z0lzYqq/S1TYxKqL0rJMPw==
 Origin: http://localhost:3000
 DNT: 1
 Connection: keep-alive
```

Chrome Request Headers (Worked)

```
 Host: sapco.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com
 Connection: keep-alive
 Content-Length: 123803
 Pragma: no-cache
 Cache-Control: no-cache
 DNT: 1
 Content-MD5: ujNHxwCuwZ1mak927GUX3g==
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36
 Content-Type: image/jpeg
 Accept: */*
 Origin: http://localhost:3000
 Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
 Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
 Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
 Referer: http://localhost:3000/
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
 Accept-Language: en
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard refreshing resolved the issue.